# iPhone SDK: Creating a menu

Tags: iphone, menu

I'm developing a few arcade games. Unfortunately, all of them lack a menu. What's the best way to create a menu for an iPhone game?

Comment: It's spelled iPhone, not Iphone :)

Comment: the same thing anyway ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a grouped style UITableView with a custom header/footer.  You can also customize the UITableViewCell as well.

Check out this link, he creates the menu you are looking for fairly easily: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-unique-looking-tables-with-custom-cells.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom class that inherits from a UIView. Just make the UIView as big as the screen when you load it and bring it to the front. Then you can customize your screen and make it look good rather than boring and tasteless like the one above.